# how to change cached picture from javascript

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I have a asp image control. ImageUrl="images/avator.jpg". I'm changing this picture on the server and then setting imageUrl same as previous url on the client. but image don't changed. When i click refresh button, image changed. 
How to change cached image won't changing url?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add random number as a paramentr to avoid caching.

```
<img src="http://someurl.com/avatar.png?version=0.01.135";
```

The best way is to add number of application build version. So every time you change something in aplpication everything will load again.

Comment: Better use current date-time as a parameter in the URL

Comment: date-time will prevent caching at all. I do not think it is a good idea.

Comment: Using version number is best, so you will cause re-load when needed. Using date-time will load every time, even when not needed. It is a reason images are cached; they can take long time to load!